# How to create complicated constants in Tensorflow from constants

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to create a tensorflow constant based on the value of some other tensorflow consant / placeholder. Let's say the input must be a tf.constant / tf.placeholder.

How do I apply tensorflow logic to create a constant based on that constant?
For example something like:

```
 i = tf.constant(...)
 ei = tf.zeros(shape=[N])
 ei[i] = 1
```

This would not work, because

```
 TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

And that makes sense, because you should not be able to mutate a constant. I also don't want my `ei` in this examples to be variables, because they logically are constants, and should not be optimized when I run my network.

Comment: Currently, you have to construct the constant element by element (or row by row, matrix by matrix, etc). I opened [an issue in TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18383) to request an operator that allows you to produce a tensor with some of its elements replaced, since it seems to more complicated than it should in many cases, but it hasn't moved forward as of today. You will have to use concatenation, stacking, etc.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the answer and that you opened that issue. I don't understand how such a big library does not have a simple way to do such a basic thing. I've read your issue and it seems that it takes months only to get noticed. Lacking this better API, could you please refer me to a relatively simple way to do the operation I asked about?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.scatter_nd` for this purpose. [The documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) is a bit dense, but a simple usage could be something like

```
i = tf.constant(...)  # assuming this is a scalar int tensor
ei = tf.scatter(i, 1, shape=[N])
```

This creates an N-element vector of all zeros except at `i`, where the value will be 1. If you then want `ei` to be a constant in your graph as well you should be able to just call `tf.constant(ei)`.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you can do something like this:

```
i = tf.constant(...)
ei = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.range(N), i), dtype=tf.float32)
```